# Embedding Flash in 3D-rendering binary

Tags: c++, flash, user-interface, embed

I want to embed Flash (2D GUI) in my 3D game C++ application, and it must be portable. Rendering Flash is not enough, I need user action callbacks.

I found [Hikari for Ogre3D](http://code.google.com/p/hikari-library/wiki/Introduction), but I guess the technique it's based on only works on Windows? (It uses OLE.) Further, from what I've heard (unverified) CryEngine uses Flash.

Almost forgot the obvious question: how do I go about business?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: a colleauge recommended [this](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/gameswf.html) library. Sounds free and interresting to me, think I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I know of several game developers that are using [Scaleform](https://www.scaleform.com/products/clik) middleware which allows you to author UI's in flash and export them onto consoles.